# Undirected weighted graph in polytime

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I'm attending a master course in Algorithm for Bioinformatics, and I'm trying to solve some exercise in order to pass the exam. I'm stuck in this problem and I don't understand in which way I have to solve it. Could you help?
Thanks the next few lines are the exercise:

> Argue whether you believe that the following problem has a polynomial time algorithm
> Input: A complete undirected graph G with non-negative weights on the edges, and a weight bound W.
> Solution: A simple path with the maximum possible number of vertices among all paths in G of weight < W.

Comment: You can either (1) Design an algorithm to solve this problem and prove that your algorithm is polynomial-time; this would prove that the problem has a polynomial time algorithm. Or you could (2) Reduce an NP-hard problem that you already know to this problem; this would be a good argument to say that this problem might not have a polynomial-time algorithm (formally, this would prove that if P!=NP, then there doesn't exist a polynomial-time algorithm for this problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [NP-Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness), and thus there is no **known** polynomial solution to it.

It is easy to reduce this problem from the [*Hamiltonian Path problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem)<sup>1</sup>.

Given a graph `G=(V, E)`, create:

```
G' = (V, E', w)
Where:
E' = VxV (all edges)
w(u,v) = 1    if (u,v) is in E
         2    otherwise
```

Now, `G'` has a valid solution with `|V|` maximal weight if and only if `G` is hamiltonian.

(->) If 'G' is hamiltonian, then there is a path `v1->v2->...->vn`. Weights of all these edges is 1, so total weight in `G'` is `|V|-1`, making it maximal and valid.

(<-) If there is a path in `G'` with `value<|V|`, and we know it is maximal - so if it goes through all vertices - it cannot have edges with `w(u,v)=2` (otherwise it will exceed the maximal weight). Then, this path is hamiltonian in `G`.

---

(1) A *hamiltonian path* is a simple path that goes through all vertices in the graph. If a graph has such a path, we call it a *hamiltonian graph*. The *Hamiltonian Path Problem* is finding if a graph is hamiltonian or not.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but your solution find only path with all vertices and not with "maximum possible number". Your solution work but the output of the exercise is different. Imagine that all the Hamiltonian paths have a global weight greater than W (sum of the weights of each edges in a path > W), in this case we need to look to a simpler path with the greatest number of vertices.

Comment: @Irazza This is not showing how to solve this problem. This is a reduction showing it is NP Complete. It shows how if an algorithm for your problem exists in P, you could also solve Hamiltonian Path using it with polynomial reduction - making Hamiltonian Path also in P.